# Excel & VBA - Changing tab colour if first 3 letter of tab name = "xxx"

Tags: vba, excel

New to VBA in excel, but hoping to get some help with a macro while I find my feet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a workbook where I would like to automatically colour tabs based on the tab names. My tab/sheet names are often codes. Some of my existing sheet names (for example) are:

- CIS22ABC
- CIS22CBA
- NAS22XYZ
- NAS22ZXY
- MY DATA
- ADMIN, etc.

I am trying to implement a script that runs across entire Workbook (i.e. under "ThisWorkbook") that searches first 3 letters of every tab name and makes tab colours based on these letters. There are lots of sheets being added and removed all the time - so an array of names won't work.

In short, I am hoping to do the following:

- If first 3 letter of sheet name = "CIS" then Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
- If first 3 letter of sheet name = "NAS" then Tab.Color = RGB(66, 134, 244)
- Otherwise do nothing!

Again, any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will automatically execute every time you add a new sheet.

There are a good amount of events you can tie this to in order to have the macro fire automatically without user intervention. A few notable ones that may suit your needs better than the `NewSheet` event that I used below are `SheetChange`, `SheetBeforeDelete`, `SheetActivate`, etc.

---

This code will need to be placed in the coding space under `ThisWorkbook` rather a sheet or module in VBE.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case Left(ws.Name, 3)
        Case "CIS"
            ws.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
        Case "NAS"
            ws.Tab.Color = RGB(66, 134, 244)
        'Case "ABC"
            'Add as many of these as you need inbetween _
             Select Case and End Select
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers for that. Will have a go.

Comment: In the end, I went for an approach that copies a sheet, prompts for a sheet name and based on the entered name colours the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Dim name As String
name = sheet.name

If Len(name) > 3 Then
    Dim bit As String
    bit = Mid(name, 1, 3)
    Select Case bit
        Case "CIS"

            sheet.Tab.Color = 16776960
        Case "NAS"
            'etc etc

    End Select

End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. First you need to count all the sheets and then run through each of them and check for the first 3 letters. If this is true you can color it:

```
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

   If Left(Sheets(i).Name, 3) = "CIS" Then
      Sheets(i).Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255)
   End If

   If Left(Sheets(i).Name, 3) = "NAS" Then
      Sheets(i).Tab.Color = RGB(66, 134, 244)
   End If  

Next i
```